# Find and Replace Pandas only indexing each row

Tags: python, excel, pandas

On Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4.

So I'm trying to get rid of "(". ")", and "-" from my csv file in column E.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQl0a.png) is what the original file looks like. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJZDT.png) is what I'm trying to get.

Here is my code (it is editted to work):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=0)

df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.replace(['()-'], ' ')

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

But [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjzpo.png) is what happens. I was looking at [this site](https://pythoninoffice.com/find-and-replace-excel-data-using-python/) and another question on here that I have lost on how to do a find and replace but it does not work/

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert you pandas Series to string (`df['Phone'].str`) before calling the `replace` method.

`df['Phone'].str.replace('(', ' ', regex=True)` should do the trick.

Comment: So python is throwing a fit and giving an error of  'AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'regex'' when I do ```df['Phone'].str.regex('(', ' ', regex=True)```

Comment: Ooops, sorry that was a typo. Go for `df['Phone'].str.replace('(', ' ', regex=True)`

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm it's still not working, still just indexing each row

Comment: Are you saving the output of the `replace` method to `df['Phone']`? `df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].str.regex('(', ' ', regex=True)`.

Comment: I have figured it out, I'll update my code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[()-]` to remove any unwanted single character.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Phone':['(555)123-1234','(555)555-1234','(555)545-1234','(555)888-1234']}
)

df['NewPhone'] = df['Phone'].str.replace('[()-]','', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```
           Phone    NewPhone
0  (555)123-1234  5551231234
1  (555)555-1234  5555551234
2  (555)545-1234  5555451234
3  (555)888-1234  5558881234
```

Comment: So I'm also trying to implement this into a csv file where I don't know what the phone numbers may be or how many there are, would I do like a for loop here?

Comment: I'm basically trying to save the end result to a csv while retaining the other columns and replacing the the column with the ()-. I got it to print in python but nothing changed in excel

Edit: I have figured it out